# Not trigger renamed files on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following structure on my repository:

```
-src/
  - file.test
  - file
  - file2
- pipelines/
  - azure-pipelines.yml
```

In azure-pipelines.yml I have the following trigger configuration:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  paths:
    exclude:
      - '**/*.test'
```

But when I rename the `src/file2` to `src/file2.test` the pipeline keeps triggering.

How can I avoid this? It looks like it relies on the previous state of the file to trigger the pipeline.

Comment: You **did** change `file2`. Just because you changed it *to* an excluded pattern doesn't mean it shouldn't trigger.

Comment: @DanielMann got it! is there any way to get around this and skip the trigger when a file is renamed to a new name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when I rename the src/file2 to src/file2.test the pipeline keeps triggering. How can I avoid this?

If you want to skip trigger the pipeline when you rename the `src/file2` to `src/file2.test`, you could include `[skip ci]` in the message or description of any of the commits that are part of a push, You can also use any of the following variations.

```
[skip ci] or [ci skip]

skip-checks: true or skip-checks:true

[skip azurepipelines] or [azurepipelines skip]

[skip azpipelines] or [azpipelines skip]

[skip azp] or [azp skip]

***NO_CI***
```

In this case, Azure Pipelines will skip running CI for this push.

You could check the document [Skipping CI for individual pushes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-pushes) for some more details.